# Android doesn't re-enable notifications on HID report characteristic

Tags: android, keyboard, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I am working on a HID BLE Peripheral and I noticed that Android only enabled notifications on the Report characteristic only once, after bonding.
When reconnecting to the already bonded peripheral, Android does not re-enable notifications.
Thus, my peripheral didn't send any Reports.

Here are my questions:

1. Is that a bug in android, or is my peripheral supposed to remember the subscription after a reconnect?
2. How am I supposed to handle this? Should my peripheral just send reports, even if the CCCD does not get written to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Bluetooth specification a GATT Server should remember CCCD values written if bonded, so the GATT Client does not need to rewrite it on every new connection. So for every bond stored on the server, it should also save the CCCD status for every characteristic having a CCCD. Every client thus gets its own CCCD value.

So, the Android implementation is correct.

Comment: Dammit. Is there a way to circumvent that? E.g. to indicate to the Host that the cccd value is not stored? I really don't want to persist the value in flash on my peripheral...

Comment: I haven't heard about any workarounds, or anyone demanding workarounds. If you are worried about the wear on the flash, I guess you don't have to worry that much because clients generally don't change the CCCD value once written. You could maybe, potentially, send a Service Changed indication for the service and hope that the client will re-subscribe (haven't verified if this works). You could otherwise just ignore the CCCD and always send notifcations (although this might potentially be against the spec).